# CodeIgniter script not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function displayList() {
    $str = '';
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $b = '<input name="completed" type="checkbox" />';
        $a = $row->title;
        $str = $b.$a;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

This script is only displaying the last field in the database. Why is this?

Comment: Do you mean the last record or the last field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not concatenating, you're reassigning.  Do this:

```
    $str .= $b.$a;
```

Otherwise the loop overwrites $str each time it runs, which explains why you're only seeing the last result.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `$str .= $b.$a;`

You overwrite $str each time instead of adding new string at the end

Answer (score 1):

It is overwriting:

```
$str = $b.$a;
```

This string changes every loop again. If you want to make it an array, do this

```
$str[] = $b.$a;
```

If you want to add it to the text:

```
$str .= $b.$a;
```